# Redis web application

Tags: user-interface, redis

Is there any free web application to manage redis similar to phpmyadmin for mysql?

I tried to use Another Redis DeskTop Manager, but in addition to needing to install, there is no field to put the username. I would like a tool that connects to redis through windows or linux.
Or is there how to connect using windows CMD?

Most of the tools I've found like redis commander and Another Redis DeskTop Manager are from the default version below 6.0, which only connects to the default user.

Comment: Have you tried redis-cli?

Comment: how to use redis-cli on a windows machine for remote access?
What do i need install?

Comment: You only need redis-cli itself, it's a CLI tool that enables you to connect to any redis instance, local or remote. It comes with redis server but, if you don't need to have it installed locally you can, for example, use the nodejs "version" of redis-cli (https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-cli)

Answer (score 1):

There are several DBMS for Redis. You can find a related article here:
https://redislabs.com/blog/so-youre-looking-for-the-redis-gui/

Redis Labs also provide a tool (RedisInsight) https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise/redis-insight/

Regarding `redis-cli` which nitrin0 mentioned it can do the job easily, personally I prefer the cli from any of the available GUIs.

When you install redis you get two parts the server and the client. `redis-cli` is the client. With this client you can connect to any redis instance you have access. Your command should look something like this:

Local connection: `redis-cli`

Remote connection: `redis-cli -h host -p port`

Remote connection(with pwd): `redis-cli -h host -p port -a pwd`